# Python get records based on date in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, python-datetime

Here i need two records based on the date field in the list. The two records must have the older dates:

```
records = [['2019-02-01', 29], ['2018-12-01', 22], ['2019-01-01', 2]]
```

Need to display two records with older date

```
Expected Output = ['2018-12-01', 22] , ['2019-01-01', 2]
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sorted`, and parse the `datetime` strings within the lists using the `key` argument so the list is sorted based on the dates. Finally slice the list to keep the first two elements:

```
from datetime import datetime
sorted(records, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], '%Y-%m-%d'))[:2]
```

**Output**

```
[['2018-12-01', 22], ['2019-01-01', 2]]
```